# Get image from image url: IOError: cannot identify image file

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python requests to get an image file from an image url.

The below code works in most cases, but is starting to fail for more and more urls.

```
import requests
image_url = "<url_here>"
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36', 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch'}
r = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers)
image = Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(r.content))
```

If that gives an error then I try with a different header (this solved issues in the past):

```
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36', 'Accept':'image/webp,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch'}
```

However, these urls (among others) don't work. They give an "IOError: cannot identify image file" error.

http://www.paleoeffect.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/800x414xpaleo_bread_wheat_recipe-800x414.jpg.pagespeed.ic.6pprrYPoTo.webp

http://cdn.casaveneracion.com/vegetarian/2013/08/vegan-spaghetti1.jpg

http://www.rachaelray.com/site/images/sidebar-heading-more-recipes-2.svg

It shows the images fine in my browser using the urls. I don't know if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Python Imaging Library (PIL) to provide the Image class mentioned in the last line of your code.

- The Paleo Effect image is a WebP file. WebP isn't a supported format by PIL.
- The Casa Veneracion URL does not link to an image file - it returns a 302 Redirect to an HTML file. ([See for yourself](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php).)
- The Rachael Ray image is an SVG file. SVG isn't a supported format by PIL.

See bottom of [this documentation for Image formats supported by PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/pil-index.htm).

Comment: Hmm, what would be the solution? What works other than PIL? The  Casa Veneracion URL does, btw, link to an image for me. (Your link is different).

Comment: Use the link I provided to type in the URL for the vegan spaghetti jpg. See that it receives a redirect.

Comment: How do you support webp? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876502/manipulate-webp-images-in-python

Comment: How do you support SVG? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600164/read-svg-file-with-python-pil amongst others.